# Magento: inside pages showing 404 after migrate

Tags: magento-1.9

I have recently migrated Magento into a subfolder on a different server. I have, after that, created a symlink on the new server; I have done this because I want to have multiple shops running off the main folder.

1. The problem is that while homepage is working fine if I am to click on any internal links I am presented with 404 page.
2. Also, on the homepage, products dont have images.

In the .htaccess I have added few extra lines

```
RewriteBase /magento/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /magento/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/kbase/faq-troubleshooting/problems-after-installation.html) solution:
1. Log out from your admin panel.
2. Clear the store cache in var\cache.
3. Log in back.

Comment: I gave it a go, but it didn't work. I am wondering if it has something to do with magento being in the subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suspect that whether your .htaccess being read or not. To verify, make any syntax mistake in the .htaccess file, reload the page and check /var/log file in your server for errors.

If it is working fine, then make sure you have the correct settings in your htaccess file:

```
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    RewriteBase /subfolder/
```

Please let me know if the solution works for you.